# how to add space to ubuntu from an empty partition

Tags: gparted, partitioning

[image]
I want to add the space to Ubuntu from the unallocated partitions.
could you please guide me in this process.
thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create new partitions and mount them, or extend the existing ones? The latter would probably be much more difficult.

Comment: what would be the difference?

Comment: Either you have the space available below the mountpoint (e.g `/data` ), or you simply have more space in your home directory.

Comment: i would like to extend both partitions

Comment: It might be possible to extend the sda3, remove the swap partition, extend home and create a new swap elsewhere. But for the 200GB chunk, I'm afraid you have to move some data if you want to incorporate it in your partitions. But I'm no expert in partition tables.

Comment: how would i move the data(btw, the 200gb chunk was windows 8, but it crashed)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Boot with a live DVD/USB.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
$ sudo -i
# apt-get update
# apt-get install --reinstall gparted
# umount /dev/sda7
# umount /dev/sda6
# umount /dev/sda5
# umount /dev/sda3
# gparted
```

Now from gparted, you can add the unallocated space to the extended partition /dev/sda3.

Later, you can increase the size of /dev/sda5 with free space below according to your needs.

You can increase /dev/sda6 eliminating /dev/sda7 and recreating the rear end of the free space and increase /dev/sda6 in the amount you need.

In all cases, you must then find the UUID partition and change them in the /etc/fstab file of /dev/sda5:

```
# blkid
# mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
# nano /mnt/etc/fstab
```

File example:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=c676ae51-cb6f-4c0e-b4a9-76850aafa1d6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=df0ce520-b0ba-4e6b-899e-a1a615c8c10a /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=c9eb230e-ab85-4bc0-b24f-06caeac4d953 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Check and change the uuid.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

It is also advisable that you reinstall your Grub.

In the terminal continue running:

```
# mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
# mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
# mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
# mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
# chroot /mnt
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
# grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
# grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
# umount /mnt
# reboot
```

Comment: i never got a live cd, i installed ubuntu from unetbootin

Comment: Boot with a unetbootin live-USB!.

Comment: do i have to use unetbootin?